# Jquery : how to add classes in sequence?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a simple css effect adding classes to items:

https://jsfiddle.net/xjmm2k8n/

```
<div class="item">item1</div>
<div class="item">item2</div>
<div class="item">item3</div>
<div class="item">item4</div>
<div class="item">item5</div>

.item {
  opacity:0;
}

$(".item").each(function(index, element) {    
    console.log(element);
    $(element).css('opacity', 1).delay(1000);  
});
```

So if I have 5 items whose opacity is 0, I want to make the opcaity to 1 each element after another in sequence (1 second of delay)

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a `setTimeout` at this context,

```
$(".item").each(function(index, element) {    
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       $(element).css('opacity', 1); 
    }, 1000 * index);
});
```

There is no need to create a scope per iteration, `.each()` would do that for you. Internally, each would call the passed `callBack` function by supplying the `index` and `element`. That actually creates a scope for you. So it would automatically help us to escape from the problem caused by the closure.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xjmm2k8n/2/)

Comment: And your approach is like wow! :D Epdi ya ipdi laam unakku thonudhu?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Kalaikatha machi.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain functions. `:)` You may use `.animate` or a closure in `setTimeout()`:

```
time = 0;
$(".item").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
    (function (e, t) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(e).css('opacity', 1);
      }, t);
    })(element, time+=1000);
});
```

And it works: https://jsfiddle.net/u6e6mxL9/

Comment: @yarek `delay()` works only when it is chained animation. So, no. `:(`

Comment: @yarek Using setTimeout is a better approach at this context.

Comment: @PraveenKumar _only works when it is chained_ `.delay()` only works when you are dealing with animation queues.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks da.. Updated.